# Numerical solution to a non-linear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I have this Non-linear PDE
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}=\left(\frac{\partial C}{\partial x}\right)^2+C\frac{\partial^2 C}{\partial x^2}
$$

Where C is a function of (x,t)
It comes from the diffusion equation where D is concentration depending, and has the linear form $D=k \cdot C$. The PDE made dimensionless for simplicity.

I have tried to find a solution with finite difference methods but without luck, The PDE can be linearized but this will make the numerical solution to inaccurate so no luck there either.

So how can I get a proper numerical solution?

Comment: Are there boundary/initial conditions? What kind of problems did you run into when solving?

Comment: In my particular case the BC's is C(0,t)=14 and C(xi,t)=2, the IC is C(x,0)=2.
And the PDE is the diffusion equation if D linear dependent of C, so D=C*k where k is some constant and C is the concentration of some contaminant.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If $k$ is just a constant, then $D_t = D_{xx} \implies kC_t = kC_{xx} $ which is just the same diffusion equation in $C$

Comment: The Diffusion equation with a concentration depending diffusion coefficient is
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial }{\partial x} \left(D \frac{\partial C}{\partial x}\right)
$$
The k disappears because it is made dimensionless

Comment: You should definitely specify that in the question. I was assuming $D$ was the unknown variable in the diffusion equation.

Comment: Yeah I see now, thought it was irrelevant now when the constants is removed due to making it dimensionless

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [this article](https://watermark.silverchair.com/12-4-407.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAmMwggJfBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggJQMIICTAIBADCCAkUGCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQM1s9Zi0oip5k0mPtoAgEQgIICFt78ugL_ZBqAqepZ8C-ltDZL-0oC8rykxaQmC8u2Q_ywYF_2LgQlk26yTmoNcvUC3rxNzhMF-kimFSqgUD1IA0T7OFJVVYmI25J-zsde9Jj_d4027ZBjPxktFbeenSiWnSzGX4JUHxISfsJJCPV2nOPpkJVnjm3EhwhvdzOMW359XVTMMrpaD2BOVbGkQ03J_YaVxn0qmqsZ_gG6NsKlJHJ4QJHtPoh0pgLrlumU790RHrXd6R67jQlm5X6OSzBzMeaqgjYk8J4HY-3ZDdD6ylrVHS-6FcBrB5s1zjmnw1qzm4ZE2ytHhQOrdxZ2AbOiGbQVLUaKBm8aAMFwVNGKooqvx_meHlLXuPb9M0UjLgtwhvLtFnhmPXPS6IAUwA-Z8l1OKXJI_ud4iddHS3MgpoeFN1HQKxH5j6yG4W9cHudyK3KkXDGu3V4AD2CBYyB9NVCjoIF7zzMdGaC-ThWtGlZerR4uPcmYWjB3X2YZlGKHhXR3mJ9He0m9OAXehQNQgOerisjcJk4r_Agneev-WXOSFEShHA1yBqlMsm5ZMK05zj1tvqPTBCvzrg4Ny3X7yKzgmtoy0HYP3HemQVnvRHW3SNCrCBzBRsuua2tzNcUVqS5ejsKRW-0ZZOTIeBgv4uwhHrMVPx9A8l-Xo2pK90DKUc9TyrSkC3B4HvJeLwQRYjy5yES5_lGIeECgfO2on0iy532uyA)

The way you obtain the result that is shown in the article is to look for a scaling function : $$ C(t,r) = t^{-a s}  F(r t^{-a} )$$

You obtain an equation and you impose that only the variable : $x=r t^{-a} $ remains, sinceyou want a separation of variables. You obtain a relation between $s$ and $n$ that are defined in the article : $a=1/(sn+2)$. And you finish the work.

Tell me if you want me to write the whole calculation.

Comment: The link to your article is expired. Do you by any chance still remember its name?